# How do I tint an application window like this one?

Tags: macos, cocoa, tint

I am very new to OSX development.

How do I tint an application to dark gray like this one did?

[image]

is it possible to do that from interface builder? If not, how do I do that from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change window title bar color, set the window as textured in IB. Then in corresponding view controller/app delegate update the window color.

```
NSColor *grayColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:64/255.0f
                                               green:64/255.0f
                                                blue:64/255.0f
                                               alpha:1.0];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:grayColor];
```

Now the window would like this :

[image]

With Toolbar:

[image]

Note that when window is set as textured entire window will be textured. I have subclassed the view and set background to white color :

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

Else the window would like this :

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the amazing explanation!

Comment: Just one small detail. The window has a NSToolbar. I used your answer and the view itself got tinted but not the window itself.

Comment: @RubberDuck I mentioned that earlier, that when you set the window color it will apply everywhere, so you need to subclass views and set a background color as required.

Comment: No, I am talking about the window. The window is the one not tinting. It continues gray. The views are becoming dark gray but not the window.

Comment: @RubberDuck I think you forgot to set the Window as textured in Interface Builder.